# Alteração nome de um campo do conjunto de dados - PowerBI

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerbi

Olá tenho um conjunto de dados (Excel) que foi carregado no PowerBI. Quando altero o nome de uma coluna/campo no Excel o PowerBI não atualza os dados porque não reconhece o nome da coluna que foi renomeada no Excel. Como posso fazer com que o PowerBI entenda que a coluna/campo ainda é o mesmo mas que apenas teve o nome do campo alterado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os passo são os seguintes:

Vai em **Editar Consulta**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seleciona a tabela que está apresentando o erro ( No meu caso com o nome 'Plan 1' ) clica com o botão direito sobre ela e então selecione **Editor Avançado**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na janela que abrir você vai ter de alterar o nome da coluna antigo para o novo manualmente. No meu exemplo eu possuía anteriormente uma coluna com o nome *'COLUNA3'* e quis alterar seu nome para *'COLUNAC'*. Veja o exemplo:

**1 -** Antes da alteração no Nome da coluna.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**2 -** Resultado depois de alterar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feito isso, basta atualizar a tabela e utilizar normalmente.